# openSUSE Leap 15.3 wants Authentication on a unused disk

Tags: authentication, disk, suse

I had a disk crash on my PC, so I transferred all the info as I could to a new disk (Old disk is still plugged into the machine).
Now SUSE wants to access that old broken disk and wants authentication for it as well. That old disk is not mounted either.
Should I physically remove the disk out of the machine?

Regards
Frik Brits

Comment: Are you trying this as an ordinary user? If so, all it's doing is asking for the `root` password, so just type it in and let it run.

Comment: The thing is: that disk it wants is broken (it crashed) and therefore I do not use or mount, or use it,

Comment: You are not giving enough info. It's broke, how? Does `fsck` help? Is it a boot disk?

Comment: Yes I did fsck and it then fixed inodes etc. but it did not help for long. No it is not a boot disk, one partition on it waqs once my /home disk plus two other partitions